# How to change area inside mask to different RGB Value in ECW Format with FME

Tags: fme-form, rgb

I have 3 Band RGB ECW Raster files and would like to change all the RGB values within the masked area to 0,0,0.

I am using the [SpatialFilter](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/Default.htm#Transformers/spatialfilter.htm) to set the masking area and thought that I could use the RasterExpressionEvaluator(REV) to manipulate the rgb values. However I cannot find an expression which works.

I am using FME 2014 and setting the SpatialFilter to Mask = Filter, ECW File as Candidate with the Filter being "Intersects"and if does not pass, then the REV should work its magic. For each band in the REV (red8,green8,blue8) I set the the expression to

```
if ((A[0]+A[1]+A[2])>0, 0, A[0])
```

changing the last parameter for each band ...ie A[1](http://docs.safe.com/fme/html/FME_Transformers/Default.htm#Transformers/spatialfilter.htm), A[2]...but this changes the whole image to 0,0,0. This doesn´t seem to be working.

Comment: Could it be a problem with my mask. My mask is a polygon shapefile containing a rectangle with a hole in it. Can I use a polygon with a hole as a mask to tell fme to only use the area filled and not the hole...or does fme fill in the hole when applying the spatial filter?

Comment: If you are pointing to the hole, try removing the hole with DonutHoleExtractor first.

Comment: Is your polygon in the same coordinate system as your raster?  FME doesn't reproject on the fly like other GIS programs.  You may need to add a reprojector first.  Otherwise, your polygon might not overlap the raster and therefore not behave as a mask.